# Zip Code missing leading 0 when retrieved from mySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am storing 5 digit zip codes in mySQL tables as CHAR(5). However when a zip code with leading zeroes (ie. 02138) is retrieved from the tables, it becomes 2138. Since it is being stored in the tables as 02138 (checked with phpmyadmin), it has to do with PHP stripping off the leading 0? How can I make sure I retain the leading 0?

I'm using quite a long SQL query string using activerecords in codeigniter.

```
foreach($q as $row){
        /// bunch of code that adds more elements to the $row array

        $data['rows'][] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: Show the code where you fetch the value from the DB and where you display it

Comment: Now show the code where you display the zip code. PHP will convert an all digit string into a numeric type but only if it thinks it has to. Are you using the zip code field anywhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str_pad($zip, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: It should be done, if we have $zip as numeric. It`s more workaround. Here we should find the root of problem.

Comment: your solution works perfectly, but it`s more like workaround, when we are hiding the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is MySQL ZEROFILL. Specify the column as zerofill.

Comment: i already stored it as 02138 as CHAR(5) with the leading 0. Do i still need zerofill?

Comment: Yes. If the field is an integer, zero isn't saved. I like @tandu solution below as well.

Comment: How can this work with international codes?  It would seem that this solution would require more than 5 character spaces, which would add too many zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

display it as text instead of as a number

Comment: how do i make it display as a text in php? I am guessing php automatically converts to a number when it sees its all digits?

Comment: You should set your data type for the field as varchar(10) - This will set your field to 10 characters long. I'm saying 10 for the 5+4 style zip. Otherwise varchar(5) should work. Because int do not start with 0, the 0 is removed.

Comment: Hi - how is it getting added? Maybe your code is stripping out the leading zero. I just tested adding 06605 to a field set with varchar(255) and it did not strip out the leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick-n-dirty workaround see @tandu version. But here you should find the root of the problem.
What happens is clear -- somewhere PHP converts string "012345" into int 12345.
So now you should somehow find, who do so and when. `var_dump` values and see if they string or int.

May be somewhere in your framework you specify column type as numeric, but it actually char in your DB.